# Javascript - Make dropdown selection

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to javascript trying to automate a selection of dropdown field. I was able to open the dropdown for size selection at https://www.nakedcph.com/en/product/8514/puma-rs-x3-rubiks-373428-001 with `getElementsByClassName()` function.

Now if I inspect the website, the different sizes in dropdown seem to be identified by data-value field not ID or classname or similar. Any help on how to tell javascript to select something in the dropdown?

THanks
Felix

Answer (score 0):

My workaround will be something like finding the appropriate 'a' tags with query selector using attribute 'data-target' and then searching for the required size by looking through these 'a' tag text and select that particular tag by programmatically clicking it.

This would look something like:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-target='#product-form-select']");
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if("36"==a[i].innerText){ //change 36 with required size
        var x=a[i];
        x.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

You can test it by running it in console

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that this code depends on the page's source code having the same structure and class names for the dropdown elements.

```
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("product-form-dropdown-btn");
if(dropdowns.length > 0){
    var dropdown = dropdowns[0];
    var items = dropdown.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item");
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].innerText.trim() == "36"){
            dropdown.click();
            items[i].click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```